# Top aligning text contents of two parboxes or minipages

Tags: vertical-alignment, fontsize, minipage

I'd appreciate help top aligning the contents of `\parbox`es containing texts of different sizes as shown in the following graphic. Because one of the texts has a different size it appears to hover above the other:
[image]

Source (MWE):

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\begin{document}

\mbox{\Huge \textsc{Text}}
\hfill
\parbox[t]{4.25cm}{
I am a fish

I am a fish

I am a fish

I am a fish
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can also use a tabular environment.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Sometimes you need to adjust by hand with `\raisebox` etc but an automated solution to align at the top of the box rather than the first baseline produces:

[image]

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\begin{document}

\parbox[t]{3cm}{\hrule height 0pt width 0pt\relax
\Huge \textsc{Text}
}
\hfill
\parbox[t]{4.25cm}{\hrule height 0pt width 0pt\relax
I am a fish

I am a fish

I am a fish

I am a fish
}

\end{document}
```

As noted in the comments, by placing rules in the first line the `\parbox[t]` code aligns on the rule (so effectively at the top of the first  real line rather than its baseline).

Comment: `\vspace{0pt}` is the shorter version ...

Comment: @Herbert true, although I tend to use rules myself, partly I think as you can fiddle with visible rules to get special effects and then finally make them 0width (but odd height or depth)

Comment: small addition: add a `\relax` at the end of the `\hrule` line to make TeX stop scanning for more rule dimensions.  If the following text starts with `height`, `width`, or `depth` (instead of `I am a fish` TeX will continue scanning for `\hrule` dimensions removing text to be formatting and probably raising an error.

Comment: @BerndRaichle er yes, fixed thanks